# Devise sessions expiring too fast (hours, not days)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm moving this from an [issue on the Devise repo](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5321) as I don't know that it's actually a bug yet. I'm hoping someone can help me understand why my devise sessions are timing out so quickly.

#### Environment

Ruby 2.7.2
Rails 6.1
Devise 4.7.3

#### Current behavior

My goal was to persist sessions for around 30 days before requiring the user to login again. With stock devise, no inviteable, I was seeing properly persisted session times on my desktop browsers but short sessions, (expiring in days, sometimes hours) on mobile devises. I realized maybe I needed to be using `:timeoutable`

I installed `:timeoutable` against a User model, enabled and set the `config.timeout_in` in 29.days in devise.rb. Except now with `:timeoutable` configured instead of longer 29.day sessions, all browser sessions are closing out after around hour or two.

#### Expected behavior

Session should persist for 29.days before requiring the user to login again.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't find it. Is `:timeoutable` not the right way to achieve this?

### Update:

This issue resolved itself after moving my application from a subdomain to the root domain. This isn't really any answer but I wanted to add it here for context. Beyond that I think the next best answer would have been to adjust the rails native cookie store.

Regardless, I'm still unconvinced timeoutable is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are downright confusing because we use the same term for so many different things.

The first is the low level `ActionDispatch::Session` mechanism provided by Rails. This consists of a set of middleware that links a session identifier (which identifies a client connected to the application accross requests) with a session storage. This can really persist any kind of simple serializable object across requests and while its most commonly used for authentication it also does other stuff like flash messages.

The default session storage is [`ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html) as its by far the fastest but there are also several options to store the session data on the server. You set the expiry time of the session storage cookies through:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, expire_after: 30.days
```

Then there is what you could call *authentication sessions* which is really just storing a claim (an id) in the stash so that the user does not have to provide credentials (email, password) in each request. In Devise all this stuff is handled by the Warden gem. When you log in Warden stuffs that user id into the session storage and deletes it when you log out. This logs you in/out when using a specific client. There is no actual timeout by default here - it lasts as long as the session storage cookie.

This is where the Timeoutable module comes in. It stores an additional timestamp along with the id and if the timestamp has expired Warden will reject the user id stored in the session and delete it. Note that if the cookie actually expired before this the whole process is moot.

Comment: This is informative and I've not yet tired to extend the rails `session_store` but could. 

I hadn't as my understanding what that Warden and `:timeoutable` is the "correct" method. I still don't understand why The configuration is not working on mobile devises. I'm left to only assumes it's a conflict with the way safari rapidly expired sessions in iOS but that would make this a bug an not a configuration issue.

Comment: Safari does have some anti-tracking features like ITP which can lead to rapid cookie expiry - I'm not quite sure exactly what the issue is here though.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add it to your User model:

```
devise :timeoutable, timeout_in: 29.days
```

`timeout_in` defines the amount of time the user can be inactive for credentials to be requested again. That is, the user session only expires if he does not interact with his application within 29 days.

Remembering that to use `:timeoutable`, extra columns are not necessary, and that does not work with `remember_me`.

More details: [Timeoutable](https://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Timeoutable)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but as I read this, I don't see if adds any detail beyond what I already outlined, except for moving where the `timeout_in` period is defined.  I doubt changing that definition will change the behavior.

Comment: I did some tests and apparently the ``timeout_in`` defined in devise.rb is not working as well as defined within your own model, as I exemplified.

Comment: I can confirm that this makes no difference and the session still expired in 4 hours not the specified 29.days.